# How to send only one e-mail with mutiple pictures uploaded on power automate?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

I'm a bit of a noob regarding power automate and i'm trying to learn.
I've been tasked to create a form and link the information on a sharepoint list in a workgroup. So far, everything work but if a customer choose to upload more than one picture, when the e-mail is sent, if for example 4 pictures are sent, there will be 4 e-mail sent instead of one with the link of the picture in sharepoint.
Can someone help me or point me in the right direction in order to send only one e-mail with the link in the body for all the pictures uploaded?
Here's is a preview of my flow below.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is first to iterate the pictures to assemble an HTML string which you can concatenate to include as many pictures you want, then after the iteration finish you can use a single email action to send your message on which you are going to place the HTML string variable that contains the output of the iteration.

I'm adding an screenshot so you can visualize the idea, notice I'm using only one Apply to each action instead of two because I don't know your data structure, however, this should work for nested Loops too, as long as you send the email action after all the loops finish (outside of them).

Edit: It doesn't have to be HTML code, it can be just text if all you want are the links.

[image]

I hope this can be of help.